# Meaning of Amazon web services (AWS) API operation labels in cost explorer

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Trying to understand costs for my aws grouped by API operation. Some API operation labels are rather cryptic.

What is the difference between API operation RunInstances, RunInstances:0002 and RunInstances:0202?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [aws forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=351957), the numbers after RunInstances: are for ec2 instance running image with licence costs.

By comparing costs I've identified that:

- 0002 = Windows server
- 0202 = Windows server + SQL server Web edition